Is CDF implemented in tensorflow_probability MultivariateNormalFullCovariance?
I am trying to calculate the CDF of a multivariate normal distribution. The documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/MultivariateNormalFullCovariance lists cdf as a method of MultivariateNormalFullCovariance. But when I try to use the method, I get error messages that seem to indicate (to me at least) that cdf is not implemented for this distribution class.
Can someone please tell me whether or not it is implemented? BTW: I can understand it not being implemented, since the cdf of a multivariate normal is hard to calculate. But I just want to know if maybe it actually is implemented but I'm doing something wrong in my attempt to use it.
Package versions:
Numpy:                   1.26.4
jax:                     0.4.35
Tensorflow:              2.18.0
python:                  3.12.4
tensorflow_probability:  0.25.0

Python script:
import numpy as np
import jax
import tensorflow
import tensorflow_probability
import tensorflow_probability.substrates.jax as tfp
mvnorm=tensorflow_probability.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(loc=[0,0], covariance_matrix=[[1,0],[0,1]])
phi=mvnorm.cdf([0.2,0.1])
print(phi)

Error message:
NotImplementedError: `_is_increasing` not implemented in <class 'tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors.scale_matvec_linear_operator.ScaleMatvecLinearOperator'>.

The same error message appears when I use MultivariateNormalTriL and the jax version: tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance

It is not implemented. CDF of MVN doesn't have a clearly obvious definition. Usually people mean the total mass in a region whose points are elementwise less than a given point. But this integral is very difficult in general (and IMHO not actually a very useful piece of information). Approximate methods exist, at least in small dimensionalities, but we never implemented them in tfp. Usually the right answer here is to step back and find a "better" question to ask about the distribution than the usual CDF. Sorry! But hope this lends some clarity as far as tfp is concerned.
